# Is it possible to mock an ajax request with jasmine simulating a network failure?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-ajax

I have a web app that needs to check if the user is connected to the internet. In the implementation, the check() function promises to true if an ajax ping to a known endpoint succeeds and false if the ajax call fails in any way.

In Jasmine, I can use `request.respondWith({status:400, etc})` to simulate a failure, but I can't work out how to simulate the more fundamental error of the call not being made at all.

In practice, browsers seem to 'return' a status code 0 and readyState 4 when the call could not even be made.

How should I approach this in my Jasmine tests?

Comment: You could maybe use `window.navigator.onLine` instead to check if you still have network connectivity.

Comment: Cant you just ping a non-existent URL? This would always respond with a failure status

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. Though I might not provide you a straight forward answer for it, I'd like to take a stab at it.

The code below illustrates three such examples (tests rather). See it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/21/)

```
  var errorFunction = function(jqXHR, status, error) {  
    console.log('This is errorFunction')  
  }

  var makeAPICall = function(url) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      fail: errorFunction,
      error: errorFunction
    });
  }

  var testFunction = function() {
    makeAPICall().done(function(data, status, xh) {
      if (xh.status === 0 && xh.readyState == 4) {
        errorFunction();
        return;
      }
      console.log("this is successFunction");
    }).fail(errorFunction);
  }

  var getData = function() {
    var str = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'
    var returnStr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
      returnStr += str;
    }
    return returnStr;
  }

  describe('test ajax errors', function() {
    it('tests a failed call due to huge payload ', function() {
      var xhrObj = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + getData(),
        async: false
      });
      console.log('Below is the xhr object that is breing returned via spy');
      console.log(xhrObj);    
      spyOn(window, 'makeAPICall').and.returnValue(xhrObj);
      spyOn(window, 'errorFunction').and.callThrough();    
      testFunction();
      expect(window.errorFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('tests a failed call due to some n/w error scenario (readyState->4, status->0)', function() {
      var xhrObj = $.ajax({
        url: '',      
        async: false
      });
      xhrObj.status = 0;
      xhrObj.statusText = 'error';
      console.log('Below is the xhr object that is breing returned via spy');
      console.log(xhrObj);    
      spyOn(window, 'makeAPICall').and.returnValue(xhrObj);
      spyOn(window, 'errorFunction').and.callThrough();    
      testFunction();
      expect(window.errorFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('tests a failed call (bad url pattern)', function() {
      var xhrObj = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/postssss/1',
        async: false
      });
      console.log('Below is the xhr object that is breing returned via spy');
      console.log(xhrObj);    
      spyOn(window, 'makeAPICall').and.returnValue(xhrObj);
      spyOn(window, 'errorFunction').and.callThrough();    
      testFunction();
      expect(window.errorFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });


  });
```

Notes:

- `errorFunction` is the errorFunction that gets called from the done
  if the `readySatate === 4 && status === 0` and also all other
  `error`/`fail` callbacks
- `makeAPICall` returns the `jqXHR` on which `done` & `fail` callbacks are used.
- `getData` is a utility function which generates a huge payload: used in test1
- second test is about making a dummy ajax call with empty `url` so as to simulate `readyState->4 & status->0`
- the third test simulates the usual bad request url pattern test.
- for all the 3 scenarios, I've used a jqXHR object that I created by `$.ajax({some params & async false})`
- setting `async: false` helps me to generate a dummy object and pass it over to the function via a `spy`